# python wait for process to complete

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run some jar files through python script which has 1 controller and multiple transaction and backend instances, below is the skeleton of the code.

```
group_count=4 #####variable

step1: launch controller though terminal command
step2: for i in range(group_count):
         launch transaction through terminal command
         launch backend through terminal command
step3: after launching these i want the code to wait until the controller is complete.
```

1. how do i get the process id of controller and wait until it completes
2. how do i launch these processes in background

Comment: What do you have so far?  There are a lot of ways to launch processes with the `subprocess` module.  Some of them wait, some of them don't, some of them let you wait later.

Comment: I am using subprocess.Popen, the problem is with launching everything and running in background.. for example the below command is to be run for 4 times, if i give 2&1 in the command to run in background my code completes after launching all JVMs
java  {JAVA_OPTS_TI} {SPEC_OPTS_TI} -jar ../specjbb2015.jar -m TXINJECTOR -G={GROUPID}

Comment: You need to read the documentation.  `Popen` objects have a `wait` method that waits for the process to complete.